# How to pass scope variables from my controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a controller variable

```
         $scope.submitQuestion = function(){
         $scope.post.createdTime = createdtime;
         $scope.post.creator = $scope.user.profile.username;
         $scope.post.creatorUID = $scope.user.uid;
           $scope.post.creatorpic = $scope.user.profile.userpic;
        $scope.post.postmedia = $scope.object.video.info.uuid;
        $scope.post.postmediaimage = $scope.object.image.info.uuid;
       Post.create($scope.post).then  (function(ref) {

    $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());

     });

     };
```

And this is my view I am planning to use

```
         <body>
       <div id="player"></div>
         <script>
          var player = new Clappr.Player({source: 
             {{post.postmedia}} , parentId: "#player"});
        </script>
        </body>
```

Is it possible to pass my scope variable $scope.post.postmedia to the script tag ?

Comment: Yes, have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237551/use-scope-variable-in-a-javascript-function-called-from-the-html-code-angular

Comment: Karthik – try to explain why controller is not enough good place for creating new objects and you want to do this in the view.

Comment: Krzysztof I did try to use the controller but the script binds to player div , I am new to angular and am not sure how to bind the player variable to div id - 'player' in the controller.

Comment: I did try this to pass object from controller                                                                  var player = new Clappr.Player({source: 
             $scope.post.postmedia , parentId: "#player"});

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way to use `$window` service. Its equal to javascript's `window` object. You should assign a **`attribute to window object`** first and use this global variable value from anywhere in your multiple js files.

You should inject `$window` service first in your controller. Your controller declaration will look like

```
angular.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window){
    $window.post.postmedia = $scope.object.video.info.uuid; // Assign value first
}])
```

Now you can use this attribute value from everywhere. Like

```
<script>
     var player = new Clappr.Player({source: 
     post.postmedia , parentId: "#player"}); //post.postmedia will work if it will have been assigned first else it will show undefined
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Vineet thanks for the reply .. I did try it and got post undefined error !

Comment: try `window.post.postmedia` in script tag

Comment: Willl you please create fiddle so I can check myself ?